# Swap two values on a stack

Tags: c++, stack, swap

I want to swap the two values on the top of a `std::stack<double>`. Is there a better way than the following to do that ?

```
void swap_top(std::stack<double>& stack)
{
  double a = stack.top();
  stack.pop();
  double b = stack.top();
  stack.pop();
  stack.push(a);
  stack.push(b);
}
```

Comment: Well, you could write a generic function, but apart from that... nope.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With a plain stack, there's no better way.

Interestingly, the `stack` adapter actually exposes the underlying container as a protected member. This means that you can do this:

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::deque<T>>
class stack_ex : public std::stack<T, Container> {
public:
  using stack_ex::stack::stack;
  void swap_top() {
    auto last = c.rbegin();
    auto before_last = std::prev(last);
    std::iter_swap(last, before_last);
  }
};
```

Comment: Nice! TIL something. Only that I think it should be `std::next`, not `prev`.

Comment: Quite complex, but interesting solution !

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with less stack operations but using `std::swap`, though I doubt it will be faster:

```
double a = stack.top();
stack.pop();
std::swap(a, stack.top());
stack.push(a);
```

Or just don't use `stack`, use the underlying container (such as `deque`, `vector`, or `list`) directly.

Comment: I'm writing a execution module able to evaluate mathematical expressions. The stack is perfect for that ! :-)

Comment: @Caduchon apparently not *perfect* since you need to swap elements efficiently.

Comment: SWAP is one of the basic command I decied to use on the stack to simplify my basic language. For example, I evaluate the operator > by calling SWAP and LESS, or I evaluate AND with NEG SWAP NEG OR NEG. If I have performance problem, my solution will probably be add more basic commands.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty much the standard way to do it, isolating the "complex" code to a function so you never have to worry about it again. Of course, it would be better as a template function so it wouldn't be tied to `double`-type stacks.

Alternatively you could sub-class the stack (either a real `is-a` sub-class or a `has-a` variant) and provide that functionality as extra. But then you'd *still* have to write that code *as well as* all the code required for sub-classing :-)

Comment: It's not really the problem. But I'm worried about performance. It's a lot of instructions for a very small thing...

Comment: @Caduchon, I seriously doubt you'll find a faster way unless you implement your own queue, tailored to your use case. I also don't think performance will be a real issue. If you're worried, remember the first law of optimisation: _measure, don't guess!_

Answer (score 1):

I do not know whether it is a better way but at least it is an alternative way.

```
void swap_top(std::stack<double>& stack)
{
  double a = stack.top();
  stack.pop();

  swap( a, stack.top() ); 
  stack.push(a);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, and I'll explain why.

Imagine there is a stack of plates where you can only see the top one. The only way you have access to the plate second from the top is if you were to remove the top plate. Now consider you have removed the top plate. The plate that was previously second from the top is now at the top. How do you modify this plate without first extracting it from the stack? It's not possible and so you extract it. At this point, the fastest way to swap the elements is to simply put them back but in the reverse order in which they were extracted. Which is what you have.

Answer (score -1):

you can take one queue and do it.

Stack: 
50
40
30
20
10

pop first two element and inser in the queue ->->

Queue: 50 40   <- deueue 50 and 40 and oush to the stack then you will get

Stack
40
50
30
20
10